# Sending Commands to Konsole Terminal

Tags: konsole

I like to be able to send a command when I launch the Konsole in RedHat 5. Eg.

```
$ konsole -e "sleep 30"
```

What is happening is the "sleep 30" is becoming the title and I am getting an error saying that

```
Konsole is unable to open a PTY (pseudo teletype). It is likely that this is due to an incorrect configuration of the PTY devices. Konsole needs to have read/write access to the PTY devices."
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave out the quotes. Assuming Konsole's `-e` option works like xterm's and others', the first argument following the `-e` is the command name to be executed while the remaining arguments are passed to the command. So you were trying to run a program called `sleep 30` rather than `sleep`.

If that's the issue, the error message looks worth a bug report. It should be complaining about failure to execute the command.

Comment: Awesome. It didn't occur to me to leave the quotes out.